# How to change the theme or look & feel of form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

Recently I have created the form in custom list however, it looks like word document. I want to standardize the form in such way that it should appear like standard form.

Is there any way to change the theme of form ?

Comment: can you post print screen of it?

Comment: Its confidential I have created the form with tables and set of questions.  When people open the form in sharepoint it should look standard.